# How to configure Spring boot to convert a request encoded in a different encoding than UTF-8

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, character-encoding

### Problem

I have a legacy application that uses Apache CXF (JAX-RS) and Spring, which accepts requests with the content type `application/json; charset=Windows-1252` in the request body. Now, I'm migrating this application to Spring Boot 2 and I have this issue:

My Spring Boot application can't handle correctly this request:

```bash
{
    "text": "Apenas um teste técnico çâãéüûà"
}
```

It handles as:

```bash
{
    "text": "Apenas um teste tÃ©cnico Ã§Ã¢Ã£Ã©Ã¼Ã»Ã "
}
```

If the client uses the content-type `application/json; charset=UTF-8`, everything works, but I have no control over my clients, So I can't ensure it.

I did a lot of tests with some `server.servlet.encoding` configs, `CharacterEncodingFilter` configs and `RequestBodyAdvice`, but I have had no success so far.

Below you can see the tests with trace enabled for Spring classes:

#### POST with charset UTF-8 - OK

```bash
2022-11-01 21:02:20.695 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/string-encoding/v1/my-string", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-11-01 21:02:20.695 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'stringTestController'
2022-11-01 21:02:20.695 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.sap.string.encoding.controller.StringTestController#postString(HttpServletRequest, MyString)
2022-11-01 21:02:39.166 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [MyString{text='Apenas um teste técnico çâãéüûà'}]
2022-11-01 21:02:39.166 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Arguments: [org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@48c529f2, MyString{text='Apenas um teste técnico çâãéüûà'}]
Encoding: UTF-8, Text: Apenas um teste técnico çâãéüûà
2022-11-01 21:02:39.166 DEBUG 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2022-11-01 21:02:39.166 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [MyString{text='Apenas um teste técnico çâãéüûà'}]
2022-11-01 21:02:39.716 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Applying default cacheSeconds=-1
2022-11-01 21:02:39.716 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2022-11-01 21:02:39.716 DEBUG 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
2022-11-01 21:02:39.716 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@48c529f2
```

##### cURL UTF-8

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8080/string-encoding/v1/my-string \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
  --data '{
    "text": "Apenas um teste técnico çâãéüûà"
}'
```

#### POST with charset Windows-1252 - Wrong

```bash
2022-11-01 21:01:26.759 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/string-encoding/v1/my-string", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-11-01 21:01:26.767 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'stringTestController'
2022-11-01 21:01:26.767 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.sap.string.encoding.controller.StringTestController#postString(HttpServletRequest, MyString)
2022-11-01 21:01:42.091 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/json;charset=Windows-1252" to [MyString{text='Apenas um teste tÃ©cnico Ã§Ã¢Ã£Ã©Ã¼Ã»Ã '}]
2022-11-01 21:01:42.107 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Arguments: [org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@48c529f2, MyString{text='Apenas um teste tÃ©cnico Ã§Ã¢Ã£Ã©Ã¼Ã»Ã '}]
Encoding: UTF-8, Text: Apenas um teste tÃ©cnico Ã§Ã¢Ã£Ã©Ã¼Ã»Ã 
2022-11-01 21:01:42.137 DEBUG 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2022-11-01 21:01:42.137 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [MyString{text='Apenas um teste tÃ©cnico Ã§Ã¢Ã£Ã©Ã¼Ã»Ã '}]
2022-11-01 21:01:43.526 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Applying default cacheSeconds=-1
2022-11-01 21:01:43.526 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2022-11-01 21:01:43.526 DEBUG 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
2022-11-01 21:01:43.526 TRACE 12932 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@48c529f2
```

##### cURL Windows-1252

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8080/string-encoding/v1/my-string \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=Windows-1252' \
  --data '{
    "text": "Apenas um teste técnico çâãéüûà"
}'
```

#### Question

My Spring boot application runs perfectly with UTF-8 and handles the requests correctly for these cases. I have only to ensure the backward compatibility as it works in the legacy application.

Do I need some customized filter to convert from `Windows-1252` to `UTF-8`? Or make some configuration in the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`?

Comment: Can you post your controller method code? I believe if you receive the text in `byte[]` instead of `String` your encoding will work. Actually I think the problem is with default encoding when you receive the data in String variable it automatically encodes the data in default charset. So any encoding after that will always give unexpected output.

Comment: In my real application, I have a complex object with a lot of fields and a lot of children's objects. Beyond that, in my legacy application, this controller works even with Windows-1252.

Comment: Provide the minimum working codebase on the github to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This log line:

```
Apenas um teste tÃ©cnico Ã§Ã¢Ã£Ã©Ã¼Ã»Ã
```

clearly shows that a UTF-8 string was interpreted as windows-1252 (and not the other way around).

The explanation is this: your curl test is wrong. You're sending a UTF-8 string but claiming it is in windows-1252.

To do the test correctly, you should create a file with your JSON content, make sure it is encoded in windows-1252, and use a command like this:

```
curl -d @test-1252.json -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=windows-1252" http://localhost:8080/string-encoding/v1/my-string
```